# Is gem installed? Error: undefined method best_in_place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I added `best_in_place` to my GemFile, ran `bundle install` and the gem does not appear on the list that shows "Using...". But best_in_place does show in `gem list`.

When I try to use best_in_place in my app, I get `undefined method best_in_place`.

I do have a `GemFile.lock`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restart your Rails server, if you are working on Rails 4 , add 
`gem 'best_in_place', github: 'aaronchi/best_in_place'` into your `Gemfile` then run `bundle install`

Comment: Great reference to have